# Referencing a directory in another folder wordpress image.php

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, path, absolute-path

Code to upload an image to wordpress site.

```
  function upload_image($file, $post_id) {

    require_once('../wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once('../wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once('../wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    //require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    //require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    //require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    // upload image to server
   media_sideload_image($file['url'], $post_id);

    // get the newly uploaded image
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'number_posts' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',) 
    );

    // returns the id of the image
    return $attachments[0]->ID;
}

$result1 = attach_image_url('http://www.americanmattress.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/a/parmelee_fm2.jpg','0');
print_r($result1);
```

Here is the problem:

- Function is located in RootWPFolder/Somefolder/ThisFunction.php
- The required files are at RootWPFolder/wp-admin/includes/file.php

I am getting following error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'ABSPATHwp-admin/includes/media.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')

Comment: `file.php` loads, but not `media.php`? Sounds like `media.php` is in the wrong place because media is after file the way you have them included

Comment: Neither one of the three files seem to load.

Comment: Open wp-load.php in the root, find if `define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );` is set. If so, then use your comment-out lines

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> Failed opening required 'ABSPATHwp-admin/includes/media.php'

Suggests that ABSPATH isn't defined. Open `wp-load.php` in the root, and make sure

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );
```

is set. If so, then use these to be safe instead of relative directories:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

Comment: I made sure that it was defined and tried to use the require_once commands, no luck

Comment: Would you mind posting your error message once more when you confirm ABSPATH is set in wp-load.php? I'm concerned about that ABSPATH not being defined somehow